# Why is Gradle able to mock final classes?

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, gradle, mockito

The Mockito documentation says that you can't mock a final class and yet running such a test through Gradle works.  Specifically, I have an unit test in an Android project that has the following:

```
@Mock
private ViewTreeObserver mockTreeObserver;
...
@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    ...
}
```

`ViewTreeObserver` is a final class.

I need to support a legacy development environment in Eclipse as well Android Studio. Studio and Gradle command-line using the wrapper both pass.  Eclipse fails with

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class android.view.ViewTreeObserver
```

As well as 'why?' I really need to know how to get Eclipse to pass if possible (without rewriting the test).

The various library versions are as follows:

- gradle-2.2.1 (wrapper used by Studio and command-line)
- mockito-core-1.9.5
- robolectric-2.4
- android-20 (unit test classpath configuration in Eclipse)

Comment: Perhaps its due to the dex compiler transformation. You'll want to use [PowerMock](https://github.com/jayway/powermock).

Comment: can you create a reproduceable small sample build and share it somewhere (e.g. github) so I can look into it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem whilst trying to create a sample build as per Rene's suggestion. The test in question was missing the `@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)` annotation.

`RobolectricGradleTestRunner` extends `RobolectricTestRunner` and resolves various bits and pieces including the ability to run the tests in all of Intellij, eclipse and Gradle command-line.

Feeling a bit dumb for not spotting that.  In my defence, I didn't author that particular test...